# how to create Transversely div using css?

Tags: html, css

i want create Transversely div using css.
i want create look like show in following image.
[following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTFt5.png)

Comment: Post the code you have so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
transform: skew();
```

in your CSS.

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
margin: 0;
}

.intro {
position: relative;
width: 65vw;
height: 100vh;
left: -15vw;
background-color: rgb(47, 47, 47);
transform: skew(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @Rounin but i was done this my way. to set full screen background and create div border.

Comment: and in your example problem in responsive.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I have fixed the problem in responsive now.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?
this is a quick copy/paste that i found on a site i made..

https://codepen.io/biroplane/pen/NpLrvE

```
#sx {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 95% 0, 74% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 84% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/1920/1080/?random');
  //background-image: url('http://loremflickr.com/1920/1080/dog,cat');
  background-position: center center;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 50vw !important;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.34, -0.32, .42, 1.34);
  &:hover {
    border: 10px solid white;
    width: 100vw !important;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    ~ #dx {
      //width:100vw !important;
    }
    h1 {
      //margin-left: 25vw;
      color: white;
      @include textlongshadow(#222);
    }
    img {
      //margin-left: 25vw;

      @include longshadow();

      //-webkit-filter:drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px white) drop-shadow(20px 20px 10px red);
      //longdrop(20,#222);
    }
  }
```

Comment: please be more specific, so i can understand what you need